# Plotting image rgb value against function of time

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, matplotlib, colors

Is there a way to compute to only one number in order to represent the rgb value of a pixel in an image? I was trying to visualize my ROI color changes over time.x as my function of time and y as my rgb value. Initially, i average the pixel rgb value that I got. For example [84 90 135] = 103 and plot it as my first point, but I realised this might be wrong representation?[135 90 84] gave the same average value as well but they actually represent different colour? This mean I will get wrong graph.

**EDIT** : Sorry for the late update was trying to fix my graph. **I do not know why but i could not draw the line graph for my data, only works with point marker or round marker**

Was trying to track the color data of images when it approaches to white colour like [image]

I was expecting that the value will keep on increasing when it approaches white as decimal code for white is 255 255 255, so the trend should be inclined upwards? But i got the result otherwise, this is the result i got when i plotted b,g,r value of images and it doesnt really show me much info.

[image: This is the result I got when I plot the b,g,r value of the 99 of the images] . Code is shown below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


path = 'R:\\xx\\'
path1 = 'R:\\xx\\'

def BlueComponent(im_file):
    im = cv2.imread(im_file) #return blue value
    im1 = im[788, 526]
    b = im1[0]
    return b

def GreenComponent(im_file):
    im = cv2.imread(im_file) #return green value 
    im1 = im[788, 526]
    g = im1[1]
    return g

def RedComponent(im_file): #return red value 
    im = cv2.imread(im_file)
    im1 = im[788, 526]
    r = im1[2]
    return r


myBlueList = []
myGreenList = []
myRedList = []
myList = []
num_images = 99 # number of images

dotPos = 0
for i in range(1770, 1869): # loop to auto-generate image names and run prior function 
    image_name = path + 'Cropped_Aligned_IMG_' + str(i) + '.png' # for loop runs from image number 1770 to 1868
    myBlueList.append(BlueComponent(image_name))
    myGreenList.append(GreenComponent(image_name))
    myRedList.append(RedComponent(image_name))
    myList.append(dotPos)
    dotPos = dotPos + 0.5

print(myList)
print(myBlueList)
print(myGreenList)
print(myRedList)


for k in range(1770,1869):
    a = 'Cropped_Aligned_IMG_' + str(k)
    image_name = path + a + '.png'
    img_file = cv2.imread(image_name)

y = [myGreenList]
x = [myList]
y1 = [myBlueList]
y2 = [myRedList]


plt.xticks(np.arange(0.0 ,50.0, 0.5), rotation='vertical' )
plt.plot(x, y, 'g.-')
plt.plot(x, y1, 'b.-')
plt.plot(x, y2, 'r.-')
plt.title('Color Decimal Code Against Time')
plt.xlabel('Time(Hours)', labelpad=10)
plt.ylabel('Colour Code')
plt.show()
```

Comment: `r*(256^2) + g*256 + b`?

Comment: alternatively, why not plot a line for each of the components?

Comment: @asongtoruin any source which I can refer to this formula?

Comment: It's just a base 256 encoding.

Comment: @asongtoruin I have a trend of how my graph should look like because the colour changes is from pale yellow(at first images) to white at the last images...I am not sure if plotting  for each component will represent anything.

Comment: No - but think about it. RGB works on numbers between 0 and 255. Scaling your components by powers of 256 ensures every number represents a distinct colour - though this also means that if your red value increases by 1 your "average" goes up by 256^2!

Comment: maybe a stupid question, but what stops you from drawing a graph using the ROI's current colour at each moment? if it is just for visualization of the change this should be the only intuitive and most representative solution to your problem. the only other solution I see is a list of touples in a table or stacked graphs

Comment: It would probably help if you showed your first, last and a few images in between and also what sort of output you hope to obtain. If you are only interested in the degree of *"non-whiteness"* you could maybe use @Piglet's answer but with Saturation rather than Hue.

Comment: @Piglet have plotted it and updated the question as well.

Comment: @MarkSetchell when you said hue with saturation meaning i need to plot with 2 channel data?

Comment: Try going to HSL or HSV colourspace and plotting each of H, S and L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only interested in color you can convert your RGB touples to Hue values. If saturation and intensity also matter this is of course not sufficient.

This will of course fail for neutral values.

Please search the web for details.

MIN = min(r,g,b)

MAX = max(r,g,b)

Hue =

- 0 if MIN == MAX
- 60° ⋅ (g - b)/(MAX - MIN) if MAX == r
- 60° ⋅ (2 + (b - r)/(MAX - MIN)) if MAX == g
- 60° ⋅ (4 + (r - g)/(MAX - MIN)) if MAX == b

If you are only interested in change, but not to which colour you could for example use the distance between RGB touples.

Another option that has already been suggested in the comments is to compose a 3 byte value.

You just cannot fully visualize a 3d change in 1d in an intuitive way.

Comment: Thus was the first idea I had, unfortunately he says "the colour changes is from pale yellow(at first images) to white at the last images", which in HSV it translates just in a change of saturation (and possibly a bit of value).

Comment: @piglet will try your suggestion in the meantime...will update with the result I got.

Comment: @Piglet is the Hue value same as the HSV color format? I actually can straight away change my color space to HSV and obtain the Hue data instead of manual conversion using your formula?

Comment: @SacreD There are different definitions for Hue. Depending on which color space you are using (HSI, HSV, HSL) the values slightly differ. But this should not matter for your application. Just use the H (Hue) component of your HSV touple.